# Función me imprime CERO después de comparar los valores

Tags: c

Hice una función a la cual le envío el valor de "Y" que es un valor ingresado por el usuario, pero cuando lo evalúa para ver cual es el menor de N valores me regresa como resultado CERO.

```
int opt=0;
float temperaturas=0, total=0, may=0, men=0, TempMay=0, TempMen=0, PromDia=0, x=0, y=0;

float promedio(float total){

    return total / 24;

}

float mayor(float x){

    if (may < x){
        may = x;
    }

    return may;
}

float menor(float y){

    if (men > y){
        men = y;
    }

    return men;
}

int main(){
    
    do{

        for(int i = 1; i < 25; i++){
        
        printf("\nIngrese el valor para la hora %d del dia \n", i);
        scanf("%f", &temperaturas);


            x = temperaturas;
            y = temperaturas;
            total = total + temperaturas;
            temperaturas = 0;

            TempMay = mayor(x);

            TempMen = menor(y);

            PromDia = promedio(total);
        }

        printf("\nEl promedio de temperatura del dia fue de: %.2f", PromDia);
        
        printf("\nLa temperatura mayor del dia fue de: %.2f", TempMay);

        printf("\nLa temperatura menor del dia fue de: %.2f", TempMen);//Aqui me imprime **CERO**

        Sleep(1200);
        printf("\n\nDesea ingresar nuevos valores?\n1... Si\n2... No\n");
        scanf("%d", &opt);

    }
    while(opt != 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como ya se mencionó, la variable men está inicializada con el valor 0 al comienzo del programa.

Dentro de la función `menor`, se verifica si `men` es mayor que y, por lo que no será mayor que cualquier valor informado por el usuario.

Una forma de resolver esto es usar una constante de la biblioteca estándar de **C** llamada `<float.h>`.

[**FLT_MAX**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/float_h.htm) es una constante cuyo valor será mayor.

```
#include <float.h>

int opt = 0;
float temperaturas = 0, total = 0, may = 0, men = FLT_MAX, TempMay = 0, TempMen = 0, PromDia = 0, x = 0, y = 0;
```

De esta manera, la variable men podrá almacenar el valor mínimo.

Otra posibilidad es crear un if que siga esta lógica: si men es igual a cero o si el valor y es menor que men, entonces se asignará el valor de y a men.

```
float menor(float y) {
    if (men == 0 || y < men) {
        men = y;
    }
    return men;
}
```

O simplemente inicialice la variable `men` con algún valor:

```
 float men=100;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ayudo a terminar el codigo y esa libreria me ayudo mucho.

Comment: Hola, te sugerimos revisar: [CHATGPT está prohibido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos.

Comment: Entiendo la preocupación de la comunidad por no permitir el uso de inteligencia artificial y respeto las reglas, soy programador desde hace 20 años y conozco bien los lenguajes de programación.

Answer (score 1):

Estás inicializando `men` en cero y seguro que estás probando con temperaturas mayores que cero, así que ninguna de esas es menor que tu valor inicial.

Inicializa tu variable en una tempratura que seguro sea mayor a todas y ahí obtendrás el valor.

```
float temperaturas=0, total=0, may=0, men=999...
```

PD. No sé de qué librería estás sacando el `sleep` y dependiendo de eso, puede que se esté quedando más tiempo del que crees en espera.

Comment: muchas gracias, esto me ayudo a terminar el codigo.